# prepareForSegue next screen is completely black

Tags: storyboard, segue

I am using xcode 4.6 storyboard and my app is for iPad. My main screen is a tableview and when when tapping on a cell will lead to a detailview screen.

When I use prepareForSegue (everything inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath commented), the detailview  screen is totally black but I can go back to tableview screen from without problem by tapping on the top left corner button.

When I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath (everything inside prepareForSegue commented), it's ok but when I tap on the button at upper right corner within the title bar which is for going back to tableview screen, weird thing happened as first time tap, it's animated and stay on same detailview  screen and tap 2nd time, it back to tableview screen.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    FailedBankInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    SMBankDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[SMBankDetailViewController alloc] initWithBankInfo:info];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailViewBank"]) 
{
   MyViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
   NSIndexPath * indexPath = (NSIndexPath*)sender;
   destination.title= [[detailRow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"title"]

}
```

Appreciate anyone please assist. Thanks in advance!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

ok I got it ! I got it !

comment everything in didSelectRowAtIndexPath function.

Change prepareForSegue to

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"DetailViewBank"]) 
{
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
   MyViewController *destination = (MyViewController *)segue destinationViewController;
   destination.title= self.title;

}
```